# Parsing data via Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, arduino

I send a string of data separated by a special character "," from Arduino when checking on a PC, everything is fine, the PC receives the sent data, but when I try to implement it in Android it does not work. I will be glad to get help

Arduino Code:

```
polojeniye = serv1.CheckPosition();
      Serial.print("drive1=");
      Serial.print(polojeniye);
      Serial.print(",");
      polojeniye = serv2.CheckPosition();
      Serial.print("drive2=");
      Serial.print(polojeniye);
      Serial.print(",");
      polojeniye = serv3.CheckPosition();
      Serial.print("drive3=");
      Serial.print(polojeniye);
      Serial.print(",");
      polojeniye = serv4.CheckPosition();
      Serial.print("drive4=");
      Serial.print(polojeniye);
      Serial.print(",");
      polojeniye = serv5.CheckPosition();
      Serial.print("drive5=");
      Serial.print(polojeniye);
      Serial.print(",");
```

Android Code:

```
h = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                                   // если приняли сообщение в Handler
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                    sb.append(strIncom);                                                // формируем строку
                    int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // определяем символы конца строки
                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                            // если встречаем конец строки,
                        String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);               // то извлекаем строку
                        sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // и очищаем sb
                        String[] result = sbprint.split("\\,");
                        for (int i=0; i<result.length; i++){
                            String[] command = result[i].split("=");
                            if(command[0].compareTo("drive1")==0) {
                                t1.setText(command[1]);             // обновляем TextView
                            }
                            if(command[0].compareTo("drive2")==0) {
                                t2.setText(command[1]);             // обновляем TextView
                            }
                            if(command[0].compareTo("drive3")==0) {
                                t3.setText(command[1]);             // обновляем TextView
                            }
                            if(command[0].compareTo("drive4")==0) {
                                t4.setText(command[1]);             // обновляем TextView
                            }
                            if(command[0].compareTo("drive5")==0) {
                                t5.setText(command[1]);             // обновляем TextView
                            }
                        }
                        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ответ от Arduino: " + sbprint, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        set.setEnabled(true);
                        reset.setEnabled(true);
                        menu.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    //Log.d(TAG, "...Строка:"+ sb.toString() +  "Байт:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
                    break;
            }
        };
    };
```

Comment: Please add more information on what isn't working. Error messages, some debugging you've done etc. Thanks.

Comment: The fact is that compilation errors do not occur, I send a command to the Arduino, to which I should receive a response in the form of a string, but my TextView is not updated in Android.

Comment: You get RECIEVE_MESSAGE from BT class?

Comment: public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);        // Получаем кол-во байт и само собщение в байтовый массив "buffer"
                    h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();     // Отправляем в очередь сообщений Handler
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }